# Terraform - Add tags to failover SQL databases

Tags: terraform, azure-sql-database, failover, azure-sql-server, azure-rm

I am trying to figure out a way to add tags to the failover DBs created with the help of terraform registry - azurerm_mssql_failover_group.

if I use the tags field mentioned as part of terraform documentation, it adds tags to the failover group but it does not set tags on the failover databases created.

My code for the resource group is as below

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_failover_group" "sql-database-failover" {

  name      = "sqldatabasefailover1"
  server_id = "Id of Primary SQL Server"
  databases = [
    "Id of primary SQL dbs"
  ]
  partner_server {
    id = "Id of secondary (failover) SQL server"
  }
  read_write_endpoint_failover_policy {
    mode          = "Automatic"
    grace_minutes = 60
  }
  tags            = local.common_tags

}
```

I tried looking for terraform registry which can help us add tags to the already present DB but could not find any. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards Tarun

Comment: "failover databases created" the failover db does not exist when you run your tf, so there is no way to add tags to it.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Is there any way to create tags to the secondary DBs once they are created via Terraform

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment .***

I created local tags as below and tried to add to failover group.

Code referred from : [azurerm_sql_failover_group | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_failover_group)

**Code:**

```
locals {
  resource_tags = {
    project_name = "failovergroup",
    category     = "devbackupresource"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "primary" {
  name                         = "ka-sql-primary"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = "southeastasia"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "xxx"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "secondary" {
  name                         = "ka-sql-secondary"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = "westeurope"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "xxx"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "db1" {
  name                = "kadb1"
  server_id  = azurerm_mssql_server.primary.id
}



resource "azurerm_mssql_failover_group" "example" {
  name                = "kav-example-failover-group"
 server_id = azurerm_mssql_server.primary.id
  databases           = [azurerm_mssql_database.db1.id]
  tags = local.resource_tags

  partner_server {
    id = azurerm_mssql_server.secondary.id
  }

  read_write_endpoint_failover_policy {
    mode          = "Automatic"
    grace_minutes = 60
  }
}
```

But the tags are not added to secondaryDb which is intended for failover group.

[image]

[image]

You can use the tags in Secondary Db resource block ” azurerm_mssql_server” for secondary as below.

```
locals {
  resource_tags = {
     ...
  }
}
 

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "secondary" {
  name                         = "ka-sql-secondary"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = "westeurope"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "pa$$w0rd"
  tags                         = local.resource_tags
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_failover_group" "example" {
  name                = "kav-example-failover-group
 server_id = azurerm_mssql_server.primary.id
  databases           = [azurerm_mssql_database.db1.id]
   ...
}
```

This created tags to my secondary sql server in azure .

[image]

---

**Edit:**

***[tag-support-microsoftsql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support#microsoftsql)***

[image]

See  Auto-failover groups [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-sql-db?tabs=azure-powershell&view=azuresql#limitations) .One may need to create tags manually .

> Also Note: Database restore operations don't restore the tags of the
> original database.

Comment: The problem I am facing is that the tags are not coming for secondary DBs, in your snapshot, u r showing for SQL server (and not db)

Comment: AFAIK tags to failover group- DB is not supported.Please check the reference docs in edit.